# .NET Module vs Assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I've been trying to wrap my head around the 'right' answer to this?  there are a couple of topics on stackoverflow that covers this, but that conflicts somewhat with msdn documentation.

for example, note the diagram in the 2nd answer to his question: [What is a Managed Module (compared to an Assembly)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326556/what-is-a-managed-module-compared-to-an-assembly)

Now look at the msdn diagram: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zst29sk2(VS.100).aspx

the msdn diagram implies that a single-file assembly does not comprise of a module, but rather of a manifest, il code, type metadata, etc.
This is different than many other articles i've read which states that a single file assembly has one module.

What is the answer? If the answer is 'both', then is the module a separate phyical file that is linked via the assembly manifest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a module in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645728/what-is-a-module-in-net)

Comment: See also this MSDN blog [Netmodule vs. Assembly](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2005/02/12/netmodule-vs-assembly/): "*In .Net framework Assembly is the minimum unit of deployment. You cannot deploy anything less than an assembly [...] Netmodule is a unit of compilation.  A compiler may give the option to compile a collection of source files into an assembly, or a netmodule [...] A netmodule can not be deployed alone. It has to be linked into an assembly.*"

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Every assembly has at least one module.  It is an implementation detail that's highly invisible.  But you can see it when you use Reflection.Emit.  From the sample code for the [AssemblyBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.aspx):

```
AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssemblyExample");
AssemblyBuilder ab = 
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
        aName, 
        AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

// For a single-module assembly, the module name is usually
// the assembly name plus an extension.
ModuleBuilder mb = 
    ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");

TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(
    "MyDynamicType", 
     TypeAttributes.Public);
```

Note the use of the ModuleBuilder class, types are added to a module.  That an assembly can contain multiple modules is pretty irrelevant, the build environment doesn't support it.  Not just the IDE, MSBuild doesn't support it either.  You'd have to write a build script yourself to use [al.exe, the assembly linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex.aspx).  There are no good reasons to do this that I can think of, all .NET compilers already know how to generate a single module assembly directly.  Al.exe is a typical bootstrapping tool, possibly used to build mscorlib.dll.

Comment: I've been wondering about circular dependencies for a while now but was afraid to ask. I don't know **why** mscorlib and system have circular dependencies but could you very briefly explain how I could have maintain two projects (in the same solution or not) that reference each other?

Comment: @RaheelKhan the answer to that is "You don't", refactor the common pieces into a 3rd assembly that both assemblies can reference. A very common real world example of this is a plugin architecture, both your assembly and the other assembly reference a 3rd API assembly that defines all of the interfaces. You can then use reflection to create instances of the plugin and cast it to the common interface both your program and the plugin share.

Answer (score 81):

> In .net the difference between an assembly and module is that a module
>   does not contain the *manifest*.

```
//Copied from CLR via C#
```

**What is manifest?**

The manifest is another set of
metadata tables that basically contain the names of the files that are part of the assembly. They also
describe the assembly’s version, culture, publisher, publicly exported types, and all of the files that
comprise the assembly.

The CLR operates on assemblies; that is, the CLR always loads the file that contains the manifest
metadata tables first and then uses the manifest to get the names of the other files/modules that are in the assembly.

**How to Combinine Modules to Form an Assembly?**

**Using C# compiler**

To understand how to build a multifile/multimodule
assembly, let’s assume that we have two source code files:

■■ RUT.cs, which contains rarely used types

■■ FUT.cs, which contains frequently used types

Let’s compile the rarely used types into their own module so that users of the assembly won’t need
to deploy this module if they never access the rarely used types.

```
csc /t:module RUT.cs
```

This line causes the C# compiler to create a RUT.netmodule file. This file is a standard DLL PE file,
but, by itself, the CLR can’t load it.
Next let’s compile the frequently used types into their own module. We’ll make this module the
keeper of the assembly’s manifest because the types are used so often. In fact, because this module
will now represent the entire assembly, I’ll change the name of the output file to MultiFileLibrary.dll
instead of calling it FUT.dll.

```
csc /out:MultiFileLibrary.dll /t:library /addmodule:RUT.netmodule FUT.cs
```

This line tells the C# compiler to compile the FUT.cs file to produce the MultiFileLibrary.dll file. Because
/t:library is specified, a DLL PE file containing the manifest metadata tables is emitted into the
MultiFileLibrary.dll file. The `/addmodule:RUT`.netmodule switch tells the compiler that RUT.netmodule
is a file that should be considered part of the assembly. Specifically, the `/addmodule` switch tells the
compiler to add the file to the FileDef manifest metadata table and to add RUT.netmodule’s publicly
exported types to the ExportedTypesDef manifest metadata table.

After the compiler has finished all of its processing, the two files shown in Figure 2-1 are created.
The module on the right contains the manifest.

[image]

**Using the Assembly Linker**

The AL.exe utility can produce an EXE or a DLL PE file that contains only a manifest describing the
types in other modules. To understand how AL.exe works, let’s change the way the MultiFileLibrary.dll
assembly is built.

```
csc /t:module RUT.cs
csc /t:module FUT.cs
al /out: MultiFileLibrary.dll /t:library FUT.netmodule RUT.netmodule
```

Figure 2-3 shows the files that result from executing these statements.

[image]

I would suggest you to read **CHAPTER 2: Building, Packaging, Deploying, and Administering Applications and Types** from **CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter** to understand the concept in detail.

Answer (score 19):

> A module is a logical collection of code within an Assembly. You can have multiple modules inside an Assembly, and each module can be written in different .NET languages (VS, as far as I'm aware, doesn't support creation of multi-module assemblies).
>
> Assemblies contain modules. Modules contain classes. Classes contain functions.

From: [What is a module in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645728/what-is-a-module-in-net)

Really From: Bing search ".NET module vs assembly"