# .assembly and .module in CIL

Tags: .net, cil

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET Module vs Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271805/net-module-vs-assembly)

I just started to learn CIL and I saw something what confused me: `.assembly` and `.module`. What is the difference between them? Where can read about it?