# Difference between an Assembly, Module and Package in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, module, package, .net-assembly

Some of the terminologies have no defined answers, many blogs and or people have slightly varying perspectives about the term assembly, module, package.

I am very interested in knowing the actual differences and usage and using of right terms. I know the meaning of Assembly and its various classifications. However, I am not clear with the term Modules and Packages. What I think about modules/package is, its a collection of assembly, yet, I saw somewhere, that an assembly can have multiple assembly.

Could someone please help me understand the right definition, classification, example and usage with respect to .NET as well as in generic software platforms.

Answer (score 3):

This question has been asked an answered before. (At least in a similar fashion.)
[.NET Module vs Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271805/net-module-vs-assembly)

Maybe this helps you.

Programming guide:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd(v=vs.80).aspx
Namespaces (Packages from Java)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you, however, that's so difficult to understand, me as a beginner. I am looking for more accurate theoretical terms. Also, there is no explanation of module-assembly-package relationship. I understand that, always there need not be relationship

Comment: Maybe this helps you.
Programming guide:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd(v=vs.80).aspx
Namespaces (Packages from Java)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k(v=VS.90).aspx