# Why and Where do we need Managed Modules

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-assembly

I know that Managed Modules are logical code containers containing PE32 Header, CLR Header, Metadata and IL code. And assemblies can contain multiple managed modules linked using Assembly Linker (AI.exe). But VS doesn't support multiple managed module assemblies. I am wondering when and why an where we do need Managed Modules if we cannot use them without assemblies etc. Couldn't we just use assemblies?

I am sure there is a logical explanation but I am not sure I know what it is :-)

More information about what Managed Module is: [What is a Managed Module (compared to an Assembly)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326556/what-is-a-managed-module-compared-to-an-assembly)

Comment: You'll want to look at Ecma 335, chapter II.6.1, it gives the rationale for modules.  It is the unit of *code sharing*.  Very obscure, I can't think of a good use for that.  Nor did the Microsoft programmers that worked on the compilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diagram [posted at the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327051/102937) seems clear enough:

[image]

Basically, you would use a Managed Module when you want to organize your code as containers within an assembly.  In theory, this should give you better flexibility.

In practice, this hardly ever happens, as most folks organize their solutions as a collection of Projects, each having its own associated DLL.  This arrangement allows you to physically swap out the DLL without having to replace the entire (multiple module) assembly.

Comment: Can you elaborate the flexibility part in your answer."In theory, this should give you better flexibility."

Comment: Well, because it's a container.  It's the same kind of flexibility that a folder or zip file gives you.  Or, for that matter, any container that you put your things in.  You can treat it as a single unit; move it around, call it by name, etc.  But most people use the DLL as their container.

Comment: Then how does compiler decide from where of the code it will create a new .net module?

Comment: Each Project in the VS Solution builds its own DLL, containing a single managed module.  I don't actually know how you create multiple modules in a single DLL; I've never needed to.

Comment: It's not that "most folks" organize theirs solutions this way, it's that the development tools (Visual Studio) generates a module per assembly by default I think. I don't know if this is something that is even possible to change within IDE without resorting to manual build steps.

Comment: @zespri: Yes, that's what I meant.